# Settings crashes *sometimes* in Windows 8 (store) APP with file permission error

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

My Win 8 Store application crashes, sometimes, when I adjust the settings. Here are the steps to make it crash - have you seen this behavior before?

- Open settings window
- Pick "options"
- Overwrite a (string) option with same string
- Click outside of window so it will close

It either works perfectly or it crashes. If it works you can do it again and again and it won't crash until you stop the program and then restart it.

When it crashes it indicates a Win32 error relating to access violation on a file (possibly the local storage file).

Program is written in XAML and C#.

Thanks

-jesse liberty

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as though there's something missing in the validation while writing to IsolatedStorageSettings. Are you checking whether the new value is the same as the old value?

Another thing I'd be looking for: what happens when the windows closes? Are eventhandlers called where saving happens, or anything with Settings? Is the state of controls persisted?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I don't check for whether the value is the same, but it should be fine to replace the old with the same. In any case, it crashes whether or not the value is the same, and when it does the value is left unchanged.

When the window closes I get an immediate hard crash (asking for a second debugger).  If I debug with debugging set to Mixed (managed and Native) I see an access violation.  

The state of the controls is persisted

Thanks